# variable gets redefined inside a python function without explicitly changing it

Tags: python, function, variables

```
   def f():
        list_0 = [1,2,3,4]
        p = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        for i in list_0:
            x = p
            x[i] ="L"
            print(x)
            print(p)
    f()
```

> Wanted the result to be: 
>     0,"L",2,3,4,5,6,7,8 , 
>     0,1,"L",3,4...... and so on , 
>   but got , 
>     0,"L",2,3,4,5,6,7,8 , 
>     0,"L","L",3,4,5,6,7,8.. so one, the "L" was getting saved 
>   . How do i change the code such that the variable p does not change and remains the same

Comment: `x = p` make x and p refer to the *same objects*. The *variable* isn't re-defined, you merely are mutating the same object, referenced by two different variables.

Comment: The problem simply happens because `x` gets assigned to the same `p`. So, when `x` changes, `p` gets changed as well. To fix that, you need to create a copy from `p` like so: `x = p.copy()`

Comment: read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in this way:-

```
def f():
    list_0 = [1,2,3,4]
    p = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    for i in list_0:
        x = p.copy()
        x[i] ="L"
        print(x)
        print(p)
f()
```

Comment: there is no need to `import copy`, `list` objects (and most built-in containers) have a `.copy()` method

Comment: You don't even need `copy` module as `list` has a method called `copy()` already You need to use this `x = p.copy()`